# Discord Reaction Roles not working after the bot restarts

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Recently I decided to update my Discord Bot from **V12** to **V13** and I encountered a problem with my Reaction Roles.
It only works if the bot doesn't restart. It worked perfectly on **discord.js 12.5.3** and now I'm using **discord.js 13.5.0**. Could you guys help me with the problem?

Here is my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ 
  intents: 32767,
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
   });
const config2 = require("../config2");

module.exports = async (client, message, args) => {

 client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
if (message.content.startsWith("22ar")) {
  
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#FFA500')
                .setTitle(`Pick the roles`)
                .setDescription(` **- You unlock yourself.**
              ✅ **- You get access to the server.**
               **- You get notified for X things.**
              
             [, ✅] - obligatory.
             [] - optional.
             \`Wait at least 30 seconds and try again if you don't get the roles.\``)
     const msg = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [ embed ] })
      msg.react('')
      msg.react('✅')
      msg.react('')
   }
})


  const CHANNEL = config2.ROLECHANNEL; 
  const UROLE = config2.UNLOCKROLE; 
  const MROLE = config2.MEMBERROLE; 
  const NROLE = config2.NOTIFYROLE; 


  const unlockEmoji = '';
  const checkEmoji = '✅';
  const notifyEmoji = '';


  client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.partial) { 
      try {
          await reaction.fetch(); 
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Fetching message failed: ', error);
          return;
      }
  }
  if (!user.bot) {
    if(reaction.message.channel.id === CHANNEL) {
      if (reaction.emoji.name == checkEmoji) { 
          const memberRole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === MROLE);
          const { guild } = reaction.message 
          const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
          member.roles.add(MROLE);
      }
  if (reaction.emoji.name == unlockEmoji) {
        const unlockRole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === UROLE);
        const { guild } = reaction.message 
          const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
        member.roles.remove(UROLE)
  }
  if (reaction.emoji.name == notifyEmoji) {
        const notifyRole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === NROLE);
        const { guild } = reaction.message 
          const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
        member.roles.add(NROLE)
}
}
  client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.partial) { 
        try {
            await reaction.fetch(); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Fetching message failed: ', error);
            return;
        }
    }
    if (!user.bot) {
      if(reaction.message.channel.id === CHANNEL) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name == checkEmoji) { 
            const memberRole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === MROLE);
            const { guild } = reaction.message 
            const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
            member.roles.remove(memberRole);
        }
    if (reaction.emoji.name == unlockEmoji) {
          const unlockRole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === UROLE);
          const { guild } = reaction.message 
          const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
          member.roles.remove(unlockRole)
    }
    if (reaction.emoji.name == notifyEmoji) {
          const notifyRole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === NROLE);
          const { guild } = reaction.message 
          const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
          member.roles.remove(notifyRole)
    }
  }
}
  })
}
  })

}
```

I am not getting any error in the console and the bot continues to work as usual.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Is the message in DM?

Comment: The message is not in DM. Whenever I use the command **22ar**, it will give me the Message Embed with the reactions on it. If the Embed with the reactions is in the **CHANNEL** and I react to it, it will give me the specified role. As I stated before, the code works fine if the bot doesn't restart. It used to work even after the restart on Discord V12.

Comment: Do you have GUILD_MEMBERS intent enabled?

Comment: @Murus i see message partial is also enabled, so i'll also check message partial and fetch message before processing

Comment: @MrMythical I have enabled GUILD_MEMBERS intent. Still the same thing.

Comment: And @a4arpan, could you please explain me what should I do in this case? Cause I don't quite understand. Thank you

Comment: @Murus like you are checking for reaction.partial and fetching reaction await reaction.fetch();, also check for reaction.message.partial and await reaction.message.fetch();

Comment: @a4arpan I checked and it does the same. It works only if the bot doesn't restart.

Comment: thats super strange, I double checked my messageReactionAdd and its working fine with similar settings. no errors?

Comment: @a4arpan Sorry for the late comment but, no sir, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Messages sent before your bot started are uncached unless you fetch them first. By default, the library does not emit client events if the data received and cached is not sufficient to build fully functional objects. Since version 12, you can change this behavior by activating partials.

Official guide about this [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages) (Listening for reactions on old messages).

Comment: The OP already enabled the partials

Comment: I already have the partials enabled and it doesn't work after the restart goes.